# PostsgreSQL Advanced Insert Statement

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

Table 1: Schema for the bookworm database. Primary keys are in bold. There are some foreign key references to link the tables together; you can make use of these with natural joins.

Author( **aid**, alastname, afirstname, acountry, aborn, adied).

Book( **bid**, btitle, pid, bdate, bpages, bprice).

City( **cid**, cname, cstate, ccountry).

Publisher( **pid**, pname).

Author_Book( **aid**, **bid**).

Publisher_City( **pid**, **cid**).

Ok, so this question is for extra credit and I really want to get it right but cant seem to do so. Trying to learn a little extra never hurt, so any help here is greatly appreciated as I'm completely lost on this one.

*Insert tuples to represent the facts that we now have the book Induction by John H. Holland, Keith J. Holyoak, Richard E. Nisbett, and Paul R. Thagard; Thagard is Canadian, and the other authors are US citizens, of unknown dates; the book has 416 pages and was published by MIT Press in 1989; and its price is $38.00.*

So far I have tried

```
insert into Author (afirstname, alastname, acountry)
values ('John H', 'Holland', 'US');
```

syntax:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "aid" violates not-null constraint
```

and then I tried....

```
insert into Author_book (aid, bid)
values ('jhld', 'iduc');
```

syntax:

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "author_book" violates foreign key
constraint "author_book_aid_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (aid)=(jhld) is not present in table "author".
```

The correct way for only one author is what I'm working on now. I realize that I need multiple tuples for all the different tables and different values. Just want to get this correct and move forward after some help..

Comment: What datatypes are the primary keys (`aid`, etc.) ?

Comment: I think we may have our signals crossed - I was asking what about the datatype (`int`, `uuid`, etc.) I'm not aware of a "semantic" datatype.

Comment: int4 as they're all 4 characters long. Sorry, I confused myself there..@Mureinik

Comment: By the sounds of it, you might be better off defining your primary key columns as type serial. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: maybe, but the'yre all letters not numbers...@mlinth

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but I'm in the same class with this question and I saw this and tried doing it like this:

```
insert into Author (afirstname, alastname, acountry, aid)
values ('John', 'Holland', 'US', 'jack');
```

It requires an aid to input, so I gave it a random aid and then put in the rest of the information too.